# Check if array has [0][1][2] or just single item

Tags: php, arrays

I have specific array that I cant find way to distinguish if it has multiple entries or single entry because when it has multiple entries I get

[image: Multiple entries array]

And when I get single entry I dont get [0] as first entry instead I get this

[image: Single entry array]

Im using foreach loop in php to extract data from array, but when it returns single item in array, it loops 3 times for each item in array :categoryid, name and other instead once and then, of course I get error

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'CategoryID'
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'Name'

How can I check if its single item or multiple items?

Code :

```
foreach($obj["Store"]["CustomCategories"]["CustomCategory"]as $category=>$val)
{
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=getCategory(\"";
echo $obj["Store"]["Name"];
echo "\",";
echo $val["CategoryID"];
echo ",1";
echo ");>";
echo $val["Name"];
echo "</a>"; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether `CustomCategory` contains is an indexed or associative array by checking for an element with index 0. If not, you can wrap the contents in an array and then do your `foreach` loop.

```
$customCategory = $obj["Store"]["CustomCategories"]["CustomCategory"];
if (!$customCategory[0]) {
    $customCategory = array($customCategory);
}
foreach ($customCategory as $category => $val) {
    ...
}
```